# how to make gdb logging command like what windbg does?

Tags: gdb, windbg

when you turn on logging in windbg (`.logopen`), the logging output will include what you have typed on the prompt `kd>` . but when you turn on logging in gdb (`set logging on`), only the output of the command will be logged, how to make gdb also echo/log the command in the logging file?

Comment: Looks it's not possible (unless you log in terminal): http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2011-09/msg00210.html

Comment: thanks for the info. and logging through terminal is ok although not as straightforward. https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+question/7131

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to log command details in log file, you can set command trace on in gdb along with logging:

```
    set trace-commands on
    set logging on
```

This would produce desired logs !

Comment: thank! i will mark this as the answer. look into the code and the option is added in gdb 6.6.

Answer (score 1):

this is just to summarize the result, credit should go to dbrank0.

per this [thread](http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2011-09/msg00210.html), patch to implement similar feature is rejected. and alternative options is to log terminal session, see [script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15306/putty-like-session-log-for-gnome-terminal), and [other options](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+question/7131).